# node npm local install override global install

Tags: node.js, npm

If I have node modules installed locally (in the same folder as my node app) will they override global installations of the same modules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. See the documentation [here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/modules.html#all_Together...) on module resolution.  And, just to be clear, "override" here simply means that the local module is the one that will be resolved to. The global module will be left untouched, and node.js apps in other directories will still be able to use the global module.

---

Edit: it would probably also help to better understand how the global installs with npm work.  More info on that is [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/).

Comment: This may hold for modules included with `require()`, but does not apply to packages installed as commands that you may run in a shell.